# Защитить процесс от внедрения

Tags: delphi

Здравствуйте. Есть ПО, которое внедряет во все процессы, до которых дотянется, свою `DLL` и стартует через `CreateRemoteThread`. И в этих процессах хукаются многие системные функции. В том числе, `DLL` внедряется и в мою программу, что мешает её нормальной работе. Как можно не допустить загрузку этой `DLL` в мой процесс, кроме, как хукать `OpenProcess/WriteProcessMemory/CreateRemoteThread` в чужом процессе, внедряющем `DLL` и проверять, куда она хочет внедрить?

С уважением

Comment: Антивирус? Вряд ли вы сможете предотвратить влезание в ваш процесс, он всё же бежит с рутовскими правами. Если антивирус делает и вправду что-то неправильное, все остальные процессы бы тоже перестали работать. Но поскольку все остальные работают, может, проблема на вашей стороне?

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте может то что Вам нужно??
[функция VirtualProtect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366898(VS.85).aspx)

Comment: Да это я всё понимаю, к сожалению, не годится

Answer (score 1):

Пишется драйвер, который защищает ваш процесс, прерывая обращения к нему.
Копайте в сторону WDK или библиотеки EasyHook.